# VB.NET: Storing ListView Data On Selecting Each Row

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview and its first column is Class ID.

On ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged, that is on selecting each row, I want the variable ClassID to Store the value of Class ID.

What is the code that I have to use?

I tried ClassID = ListView1.Items.subitems(0).text, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It should be

```
ClassID = ListView1.Items(ListView1.FocusedItem.Index).SubItems(0).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but you forgot to specify which row you want to access.

```
ClassID = ListView1.Items.subitems(0).text
```

should be

```
ClassID = ListView1.selectedItems(0).subitems(0).text
```

Note that this assumes you only allow it to choose one row at a time.

Comment: I have tried ClassID = ListView1.selectedItems(0).subitems(0).text, but it works only for the first click, regardless of the index of the selected row. On the second click, I receive the following error:

InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index